# how to process a large Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (1.6m rows x 20 columns) that is read from a 600MB text syslog file. I read chunk by chunk and can get the whole into a dataframe.

But I cannot do simple sum on the dataframe, it just hang forever.

Do I need to split and process the dataframe? Because I got the feeling that pandas dataframe is very efficient and can do this effortlessly.

Comment: You should be able to process that quite comfortably in pandas. How are you trying to do the sum?

Comment: Hi, you're correct. The problem I found with my dataset is that the column in question is read as Object. So when I sum, it just create a long long string that hang the machine in the end. Thanks for your sharing.